# Flutter: TextFormField, change text

Tags: dart, flutter

I have this future builder that returns a TextFormField:

```
new FutureBuilder(
                    future: _controller.load(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
                    String content;
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    Map data = _controller.decode(snapshot.data);
                    content = data['x'];
                    }
return TextFormField(controller: 
textController = new TextEditingController(text: content == null ? "" : content),
```

So, at the beginning, I want that an initial value is shown in the field if the snapshot is not empty. But how can I change this text later? (because, if the user changes this field and then press "ok" on the keyboard, the old value will replace the new one)
I tried something like:

```
onFieldSubmitted: (val){
                      setState(() {
                        content = val;
                      });
```

but doesn't work, as soon as I press on "ok", the old value will appear again

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.

```
StreamController<String> someStream = StreamController<String>();

  new StreamBuilder<String>(
      stream: someStream.stream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> result) {
        // you get notified here about updates on someStream
        return new Text(currentData,
            style: new TextStyle(
                color: new Color(0xFF05164D), fontSize: 36.0));
      })

  new FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {
            someStream.add("ok");
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the TextEditingController at the class level and then set it's `initialValue` with the value from the Future.

```
class MyWidgetOrState {
  final controller = TextEditingController();
  ...
  if (content != null) controller.initialValue = content;
```